# .HTACCESS - Dump site from production to development

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, url-rewriting, development-environment

We recently have adquired the credentials to fully play with our website hosted outside.
So we need to mount it locally on a XAMPP stack to fully deploy the site and asociated database.

It've been already done, and everything seems to work properly except for the images in the site.

It is a DRUPAL site. Some images are "full path coded", so they work as we can expect, but major of them are just relative path coded.

Now, I've everything mounted on localhost. Let's say the folder with the site it's called "web".
Then i've everything on:

c:/xampp/htdocs/web/.......

So I access to it via: `http://localhost/web/`

I've tested that all the non viewing images, if I append the "`http://localhost/web/`" on the 'src="/site/..."' they are accessible and look right.

So, is there a way to via .htaccess add the "`http://localhost/web/`" on those URLs who hasn't it? It doesn't only happens with images, it's just related with all the links, urls, srcs, whatever which is just "relative pathed".

I've already tried the "RewriteBase /web", but it doesn't work.

Need help to solve this so, please.

In summarize, the site online is just mounted on the root, so everything works, fully or just relativetly pathed. But in my case, I've got the development site inside a folder, so I need it to work too!

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Drupal 7 site (might work for Drupal 6) make sure you have a tmp directory set.  Go to admin/config/media/file-system and look for the temporary directory. Also confirm that you have this directory on your root, which for XAMPP is the htdocs folder.

This might be a file permission that can be caused by incorrect .htaccess settings (This link may help: https://www.drupal.org/node/2140629) in the folder set as your temporary directory.

This may also be a document root error. You can change that by editing the DocumentRoot setting in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf.

This stackoverflow link may help if none of the above suggestions bear fruit: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30113/configuring-the-temporary-directory